# Understanding how basic celery message qeueing works

Tags: django, message-queue, django-celery

I've implemented a small test which uses celery for message queueing and I just want to make sure I understand how it works on a basic level (Django-Celery, Using Redis as a broker).

My understanding is that when I place a call to start an asyncronous task, the task information is placed in redis and then a celeryd instance connected to the broker consumes and executes the task. Is this essentially what is happening?

If I setup a periodic task thats supposed to execute once every hour does that task get executed on all task consumers? If so is there a way to limit it so that only one consumer will ever execute a periodic task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `workers` will consume as many messages as the broker contains.  If you have 8 workers, but only 1 message, 1 of the 8 workers will consume the message, executing the task.

Comment: I just saw in the documentation where it states for periodic tasks that only one instance of celerybeat should be running or else the task will be executed multiple times. Thanks for verifying my thoughts.

Comment: I think what you are referring to is that is mentions only having a single scheduler is running for a schedule at a time.  That simply means, if you have two schedulers, putting the same task in the queue then it would be executed twice.